# How can I create a letterhead template that doesn't break our company branding guidelines?

Tags: print-design, branding, template-design

I'm a director of a nonprofit, and I've been working on a letterhead for my group that we can use.

Nearly a decade ago, we had an actual graphic designer draw up a [branding guide](https://lopsa.org/art_dept/LOPSA-branding-guide.pdf) for us that we try to abide by, but I'm being stumped by the requirement that our logo not go at the top of the page (as dictated on p12).

I was wondering if you had any ideas on what the "right" way to do this is, (or examples of letterhead where this is the case?). To my knowledge, I've never seen one like this, but I'm definitely not a graphics designer by trade.

Thanks!

Comment: Few things: 1. What is "my group" refer to? You're a subset of the NPO? Does your subset have an official name and/or logo? 2. Isn't the image on the left of p12 showing you how they recommend the logo be placed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a subgroup within the NPO. And placing the logo in the bottom left corner of the page works fine as "letterhead"?

Comment: It's fine to place it there, the brand is still represented on the page. The guidelines also indicate that it should take up less than 1/3 of the space which leaves plenty of room for text on the page too.

Comment: Alright, great! If you want to make that an answer, I'll award it the checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to Ryan's answer but more a choice from your own branding guidelines.

You can use Ryan's suggestion, or you can use the one that's even better from your guidelines. The one on the bottom left:

[image]

I think it's beautifully branded by the way.

Something like this - you can pull the template straight out of the PDF you linked to:

[image]

Comment: ok ok ok enough enough you win the checkmark! I'm laughing too hard. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, and if it tickled you that's a great bonus :D

Answer (score 5):

Since you're not a Subgroup I would do:

Name, position, and contact information at the top. Maybe with a blue dividing line. Then logo on the bottom right as stipulated and leave the entire space to the left of it empty.

[image]

There's no reason to over think it.

Comment: i would put them all on the right but that's me

Comment: I'd also put them all on the right. I agree with a blue dividing line too and of course the logo is perfect where it should be, adhering to the guideines ;)